# Uploading a file to azure storage account as a blob with authentication using managed identities

Tags: bash, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-managed-identity

I want to upload a text file from a VM to storage account. For this I have created a VM with system assigned managed identity enabled. I assigned the managed identity to Storage account as RBAC policy (given the Storage Blob Data Owner permissions). I now want to upload the file in a container name log using curl request (since I don't have az cli installed in the VM). How can I do that.

The file that I want to upload is test.txt and want to upload with same name.

Thanks

Comment: Kindly share the script you have tried, and confirm on which VM you are using Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am using a Linux VM. I Don't have a script I am using the following commands

```
access_token=$(curl -H "Metadata: true" "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.azure.com" | jq -r .access_token)

curl -X PUT -T "$local_file_path" -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" "$storage_account_url"

Comment: You can upload a file to a storage account using a SAS token as an easy method instead of Managed Identity.

Comment: can you please share the details sorry I am bit new to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uploading a file to azure storage account as a blob with authentication using managed identities.

There are several ways to **upload** files to a `storage account`.

**Method 1:**

Upload a file to a storage account using a `SAS` token with the **'curl'** command.

1. Go to the storage account and generate a `SAS` token with the **required** permissions

[image]

2. Run the following command to copy the file from the **Linux VM** to the storage account using curl..

```bash
  curl -H "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob" --upload-file samplefile.txt --url "https://venkat12.blob.core.windows.net/log/samplefile.txt?<SAS_Token>"
```

**Output:**

[image]

The file has been uploaded to the storage account.

[image]

**Method 2:**  :    **Azcopy** with `managed Identity`

**Download AzCopy:**

```
wget https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-linux
```

**Extract the AzCopy**

```
tar -xvf downloadazcopy-v10-linux
```

**Move the AzCopy to a Directory**

```
sudo cp ./azcopy_linux_amd64_*/azcopy /usr/local/bin/
```

**Verify the Installation:**

```
azcopy --version
```

**Login** :  `sudo azcopy login --identity`

Execute the command below to `upload` the files to the storage account.

```
sudo azcopy  copy '/home/Venkat/samplefile.txt' 'https://venkat12.blob.core.windows.net/log/samplefile.txt'
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I tried the first approach but I am getting the error:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>ResourceNotFound</Code><Message>The specified resource does not exist.

The storage account and the container exists. the file tmp.txt exists on the VM

Comment: Please verify that the resources exist and that the file is accessible on the virtual machine.

Comment: The resources exist and I have created the file in the VM.

Comment: If the file exist in the VM, navigate to same directory and specify the same file in the cmd : curl -H "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob" --upload-file samplefile.txt --url "https://venkat12.blob.core.windows.net/log/samplefile.txt?<SAS_Token>"

Comment: It is giving the same error. This is the command that I have used

 sudo curl -H "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob" --upload-file tmp.txt https://storenodebootstraptest.blob.core.windows.net/validationlogs/tmp.txt?<sas-token>

Comment: Share the error screenshot to understand the issue clearly.

Comment: I added the screenshot by editing the question

Comment: The screenshot you shared does not show the command prompt. Please send a complete image that includes both the command and the error result. The current image is too blurry to read.

Comment: As your missing **--url** in cmd, that is the reason full storage account URL it is taking a file.

Answer (score 0):

i get AuthorizationFailure. The documentation from microsoft says, that you need a Authetification-Header